# Convergence in probability using characteristic functions

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, characteristic-functions, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

I need to solve the following problem.

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be independent random variables all with expectation $0$ and variance bounded by $M$. Prove that $\frac{1}{n}\cdot \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}{\buildrel P \over \to}\hspace{1mm}0 $

$\underline{\text{SOLUTION}}$

$\phi_{X_{k}}(t) = 1 - \frac{E(X_{k}^2)}{2}\cdot t^2 + \mathcal{O}(t^2)$

By independence of the $X_i$'s, we get

$\phi_{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}}(t) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \bigg[1 - \frac{E(X_{k}^2)}{2}\cdot t^2 + \mathcal{O}(t^2)\bigg]$

And Hence,

$\phi_{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}}(t) = \phi_{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}}(\frac{t}{n}) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \bigg[1 - \frac{E(X_{k}^2)}{2}\cdot (\frac{t}{n})^2 + \mathcal{O}((\frac{t}{n})^2)\bigg] \tag{1}$

Obviously, now i have to show that $(1)\to \phi_0(t) = E(e^{it\cdot0}) = 1$.

But how would i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows directly from the [weak law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law). Finite variance is implied by bounded variance.

Comment: So that's what i did .

We need to show that $P\Bigg(\Big|\frac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} X_{k}}{n} - 0\Big| > \epsilon \Bigg) \to 0$.

Hence using Markov's inequality we get that $$P\Bigg(\Big|\frac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} X_{k}}{n} - 0\Big| > \epsilon \Bigg) \leq \frac{E\big(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}\big)^2}{n^2\cdot\epsilon^2} \tag{1}$$

Comment: But, $$E\big(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}\big)^2 = Var\big(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}\big) + \underbrace{(E\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_{k})^2}_{=0} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} Var(X_k) = n\sigma^2 \leq n\cdot \mathcal{M}$$ 

Therefore, $(1) \leq \frac{n\cdot \mathcal{M}}{n^2\cdot\epsilon^2} = \frac{\mathcal{M}}{n\cdot \epsilon^2} \to 0 \hspace{1mm} \text{as} \hspace{1mm} n\to \infty$

Comment: Do you really need to do all that, teo theo? It looks like your conclusion is true by weak law of large numbers :|

Comment: Look at [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Proof_using_Chebyshev.27s_inequality) here. It looks like you ended up proving the weak law of large numbers for this case. Oh, I think I found a proof [using characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Proof_using_convergence_of_characteristic_functions). Don't reinvent the wheel :P

Comment: I did all that for completeness because of the bounded variance. But thanks anyway!